# Base class method return derived class objec

Tags: c++, inheritance, matrix

I'm creating a matrix class (primarily for self-imposed practice, I know about Eigen).  In it I have matrix  multiplication defined as one would expect- the method takes a const reference to a Matrix object and returns a Matrix object.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator *(const Matrix& rhs) const
{
    Matrix temp(mRows,rhs.mCols);
    ... //do Matrix Multiplication
    return temp;
}
```

I then derive a DCM class (Direction Cosine Matrix--just a special kind of matrix).

```
class DCM: public Matrix
{
    .... // class definition here, but does NOT contain definition for
         // matrix multiplication    
};
```

I can create two DCM objects and multiply them together no problem, but the object returned is of type Matrix.

```
DCM Rvb_q(q);

DCM Rvb_p(p);

DCM Rvb_pq(Rvb_p*Rvb_q); // error because Rvb_p*Rvb_q returns a Matrix object
```

Is there way to have that function return a DCM object without having to recode the function in the derived class? One way is to add this constructor to the derived class:

```
    DCM(const Matrix &M):Matrix(M) {}
```

But that seems really inefficient (creates a new object for the multiplication and then copies it when making the DCM object) and limiting (Anytime I multiplied two DCM objects together, I'd have to create a new DCM object for the Matrix object to be copied into--I couldn't just use the returned object as a DCM).  Is there a way to reuse the base class function, but have it return the derived class type?

Comment: Do they really need to return the derived type? Your inheritance hierarchy already suggests that the DCM is-a matrix and provided that the multiplication operation is the same between both (ie, it doesn't have to take into account special properties of the DCM), then it should be fine to just return a matrix, although you probably want/need a conversion constructor.

Comment: If you added a move constructor to your Matrix class, then `DCM Rvb_pq(Rvb_p*Rvb_q)` would be more efficient.

Comment: @TimoGeusch - They do.  I also derive a Quaternion class--you can convert a DCM to quaternion (which I'll define), but in general it doesn't make sense to convert a matrix to a quaternion.  So this will allow me to multiply two DCMs together and convert the result to a quaternion

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that using the [Curiously Recurrent Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). The CRTP is an idiom where a class inherits from a template class with it as template argumment. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct CRTP_base {};

struct foo : public CRTP_base<foo> {};
```

The power of this idiom relays in the fact that **the base class knows what class derives from it**. You could use that property to solve your problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct matrix_base
{
    T& operator*=(const T& rhs)
    {
        /* Multiplication code */
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

struct DCM : public matrix_base<DCM> {};

int main()
{
    DCM a,b c;

    a *= b; //OK, call to matrix_base<DCM>::operator*, which expects a DCM as parameter,
            //and returns a reference to a DCM.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anything that inherits from matrix multiplies to the same type (is closed under multiplication), then you can hack together something like:

```
template <class TMatrix>
TMatrix Matrix::operator *(const TMatrix& rhs)
{
    TMatrix temp(mRows, rhs.mCols);
    // multiply
    return temp;
}
```

But I don't recommend that. In cases like these I think it's better to be explicit that multiplying a DCM by a DCM results in a DCM:

```
DCM DCM::operator *(const DCM& rhs)
{
    return Matrix::operator*(rhs);
}
```

in this case you should also declare (possibly private) `DCM(const Matrix&) and DCM(Matrix&&)`.

Comment: So adding the DCM(const Matrix&) fixes the issue regardless of whether or not I include the DCM::DCM operator *(const DCM& rhs) function definition.  Since it works without it is there a reason I should still include it?

Also, I'm just learning about rvalue references - I've gotten the move assignment to work but just the move constructor doesn't seem to be getting called.  I'm working on a separate post for it.

Comment: To be honest, I'd just stick with DCM(const Matrix&) and DCM(Matrix&&) . The main benefit of my approach is if you want to say auto m = `dcm1 * dcm2` and want m to be of type DCM. Also, I really encourage you to take a look at chapter 29 in [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), the whole chapter goes over the design of a matrix class. I'm still working through the book so I'm not there yet, but seeing as it's written by the creator of C++, its probably a decent design :)